# How to blur the Parent Activity when a fragment is added?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fadein, fadeout

An Activity which has an image when i click the image
1)A fragment should be added in the middle of the parent activity
2)When the fragment appears the background of parent activity should get blurred/dimmed.
3)And clicking outside the fragment the fragment should disappear again.
(Same effect we get when we click contact image in whatsApp it opens an overlay)
I have can add fragment successfully but the activity remains active.

How to achieve this effect?
I have tried fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimation(int,int) but it does not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Use a [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) setting the layout in the `onCreateView()` method.
2. Add a full screen `Fragment` with a background with alpha (for example `#44000000`). Add the `OnTouchListener` to the background view and in the `onTouch()` method, dismiss the `Fragment`.

By the way, I would seriously recommend you the first option.